# Erro ao Definir Headers-Authorization no retorno dos dados no Axios

Tags: http-headers, axios, requisição

Estou tentando definir o headers - Authorization após uma requisição via axios, essa requisição retorna o token que é gerado no servidor, na linha 7 do código abaixo atribuo o token que é retornado para inserir no headers em Authorization e após isso redirecionar para a página Home do sistema, na linha 8. Porém o headers Authorization não está sendo criado.

Alguém saberia me sinalizar onde está o erro e como faço para criar o headers - Authorization com o token que é retornado com sucesso na reponse do .then, linha 5?

```
1          data = {email: email, password: password};   
2          url = '/auth/token';     
3               
4          axios.post(url, simpleQueryString.stringify(data))       
5            .then(function(response) {         
6                if (response.status == 201) {          
7                    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = response.data.token;           
8                    redirectPageHome(response.data['base_url']);
9                }          
10           })         
11           .catch(function(error) {           
12              console.log(error.response.data.error);         
13           })
```

Comment: Amigo, sua aplicação é stateless? é um SPA? Poste o código dessa função "redirectPageHome" e um exemplo desse "response.data['base_url']". Se a sua aplicação for stateless, você deve armazenar o token localmente (local storage) e no carregamento da aplicação realizar a configuração.

Comment: É stateless não é SPA, a função "redirectPageHome" executa somente isso -> window.location.replace(base_url+"/"). O base_url é trazido no response da requisição axios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, acredito que o window.location.replace possa estar gerando uma nova requisição. Se está utilizando o Chrome, veja nas ferramentas do desenvolvedor a aba *Network*.

Acredito que o certo neste caso é armazenar localmente ([local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)):

```
data = {email: email, password: password};   
url = '/auth/token';     

axios.post(url, simpleQueryString.stringify(data))       
    .then(function(response) {         
        if (response.status == 201) {
            localStorage.setItem('token',response.data.token);
            redirectPageHome(response.data['base_url']);
        }          
    })         
    .catch(function(error) {           
        console.log(error.response.data.error);         
    })
```

E então logo após realizar a inclusão do [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), verificar a existência do token e configurar o cabeçalho. Exemplo:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script>
    // exemplos retirados da documentacao do axios
    // https://github.com/axios/axios

    // opcao 1 - configurar globalmente
    var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
        window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token; 
    }

    // opcao 2 - configurar a cada requisicao
    axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
        var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = token;
        }
        return config;
    });
</script>
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica, deu tudo certo agora!